# how to open sub menu in click on menu Item instead of hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to open this sub menu in button click not on hover

```
 <div id="container" style="width: 250px;">
        <ul id="filter-menu-button-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>A</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>B</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open"></span>C</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1A</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1B</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1C</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1D</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1E</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">5</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">6</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">7</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">8</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1F</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">5</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


jquery code

$('#filter-menu-button-menu').menu({
    "position": {
        collision: 'flipfit'
    }
});
```

every thing is working fine, but i want to open sub menu in click of menu Item instead of hover.

here is js fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/tAH6a/17/

Thanks in advence

Comment: see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tAH6a/21/

Comment: thank a lot Nishit:)

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
$('#filter-menu-button-menu').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

after

```
$('#filter-menu-button-menu').menu({
"position": {
    my: "right top",
    at: "left top",
    collision: 'flipfit'
}
});
```

look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tAH6a/22/

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code . Unbind `mouseenter mouseleave` events.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tAH6a/21/)

```
$('#filter-menu-button-menu').menu({
  "position": {
    my: "right top",
    at: "left top",
    collision: 'flipfit'
   }
 });

 $('#filter-menu-button-menu').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Comment: hi nishit,  could you check this fiddle here when we click on C menu then sub menu of C open and after that when we click on B then C's submenu close but b's sub menu does n't open ..how can we toggle this     http://jsfiddle.net/tAH6a/23/